# how to find all the words in a file containing a particular string?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been given a file containing a lot of words(similar to a dictionary), but I'm not sure how to search and find the words within that file that contains a particular string. For example if the string I entered is 'hi', then the program should find words like 'hilarious' and such that contains the string.Do I use count?

Comment: `if 'hi' in 'hilarious':`?

Comment: Write your code in stages.  Start with a list of words `['hi', 'hello', 'he', 'is' 'hilarious', 'thio', 'not']`.  Write code to solve the problem.  Next, start with a string `'Hi hello he is hilarious thio not'`.  Write additional code to split the string into a list.  Finally, add more code to read the string from a file.  You need to know the exact format of the file to split it properly. `str.count` would not list the words and would double count a word with 'hi' twice.